# Downloadable Products are blank in admin order screen, also cannot complete order

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, downloadable

Running Magento 1.9.0.1, brand new install with just a few plugins on it. When a downloadable product is purchased on our website, the admin order screen under "Items Ordered" is completely blank. The order is also stuck in "processed", we cannot complete it. Clicking "invoice" just shows a blank invoice screen.

[image: Admin Order Screen]

[image: After hitting invoice]

Comment: Bump? Not even sure if that works on stack exchange. I'm clueless on how to fix this, searches come up with nothing

Comment: Did you check your pages HTML sourcecode and the system and error log for any error-messages?

Comment: I'll complete this out, it ended up being a bug caused from another extensions. Once I removed it, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a problem with an extension that I removed